# Copy input fields created from *ngFor to input fields in an outer modal

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to build a pop-up modal edit form to change individual table values in a dynamic grid. Right now, the input fields appear on button click using the function editToggle(i). No more than 4 input fields will ever appear because they are meant to edit the 4 values in my data model. However, the input fields (and values) are being dynamically generated with *ngFor. I need some way to pass/copy those input fields to my modal to edit there instead of on the grid itself (where they currently appear after clicking the edit button).

I have tried to use [(ngModel)] to clone but it does not work.  I have tried to pass them using functions but the values return null. Because the HTML only shows one input field (because they are being dynamically created with *ngFor) I do not know of a way to individually pass the values.

```
<div>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>
        List of Providers
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="thetable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Application ID</th>
      <th>Client Name</th>
      <th>Version</th>
      <th>API Key</th>
      <th>Protected Secret</th>
      <th>EDIT/DELETE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-app="tblRowApp" *ngFor="let prov of providers; let i = index">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        <span class="field" *ngIf="i !== index">
          {{prov[col]}}
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="i === index">
          <input [(ngModel)]="inputClientName" class="table" value="{{prov[col]}}" (change)="EditItem(i, col, $event.target.value)" type="text" placeholder="{{prov[col]}}">      
        </span>
      <td>
        <span *ngIf="editing && i === index">
          <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="i !== index">
          <button class="edit" name="editButton" (click)="editToggle(i); openEditForm()">/</button>
          <button class="delete" (click)="deleteRow(i)">x</button>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

```
<!-- The EDITING Modal -->
<div id="editForm" class="modal_edit">
    <div class="modal-content_edit">
      <span (click)="save()" class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 70px">Edit OAuthAppProvider</h2>
      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          Client Name:
        </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="inputClientName" id="editClientName" type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          Version
        </label>
        <input id="editClientVersion" type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          API Key:
        </label>
        <input id="editClientAPIKey" type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          Protected Secret
        </label>
        <input id="editClientProtectedSecret" type="text">
      </div>

      <button style="float: right" class="add" (click)="save()">
        <h4 style="font-style: bold">Save</h4>
      </button>
      <button class="cancel" (click)="save()">
        <h4 style="font-style: bold">Cancel</h4>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
export const PROVIDERS: any[] = 
[
    {
        AppID: "11",
        ClientName: "sampleclientname1",
        apiKey: "sampleapikey1",
        Version: "1.0",
        protectedsecret: "samplesecret1"
    },
    {
        AppID: "12",
        ClientName: "sampleclientname2",
        apiKey: "sampleapikey2",
        Version: "1.0",
        protectedsecret: "samplesecret2"
    },
    {
        AppID: "13",
        ClientName: "sampleclientname3",
        apiKey: "sampleapikey3",
        Version: "1.0",
        protectedsecret: "samplesecret3"
    },
    {
        AppID: "14",
        ClientName: "sampleclientname4",
        apiKey: "sampleapikey4",
        Version: "1.0",
        protectedsecret: "samplesecret4"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable named something like `selectedRowData` and set the provider as its value when the user clicks the edit button. The `value` attribute of the inputs on the modal can be set to the properties of the selected row. It's difficult to tell what the functionality of the other methods is supposed to be without the component code so I made some assumptions. Let me know if you have any other questions about it.

Here's a link to a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqtf9i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**EDIT**

The data is only being bound one way via the `[value]` attribute and there isn't a form object keeping track of all the changes like there would be using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) so a model should be created first.

I commented out the original solution and added updates below. The `selectedRowData` variable is instantiated with a `provider` object with empty properties. The modal has been updated to use two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]`. The StackBlitz has also been updated.

The table is updated as the user types their edits into the form. The save button doesn't need to be used unless the data needs to be persisted somewhere.

Check out the [Angular Forms Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) it should help with how to pass form data around between components. What you've created here is similar to [Template-driven Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#introduction-to-template-driven-forms).

**Component**

```
// selectedRowData = null;
selectedRowData = {
    AppID: "",
    ClientName: "",
    apiKey: "",
    Version: "",
    protectedsecret: ""
};

editToggle(rowData) {
  this.selectedRowData = rowData;
}
```

**Table**

```
<div>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>
        List of Providers
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="thetable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Application ID</th>
      <th>Client Name</th>
      <th>Version</th>
      <th>API Key</th>
      <th>Protected Secret</th>
      <th>EDIT/DELETE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-app="tblRowApp" *ngFor="let prov of providers; let i = index">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        <span class="field" *ngIf="i !== index">
          {{prov[col]}}
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="i === index">
          <input [(ngModel)]="inputClientName" class="table" value="{{prov[col]}}"
          (change)="EditItem(value)" type="text" placeholder="{{prov[col]}}">      
        </span>
      <td>
        <span *ngIf="editing && i === index">
          <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="i !== index">
          <button class="edit" name="editButton" (click)="editToggle(prov); openEditForm()">/</button>
          <button class="delete" (click)="deleteRow(i)">x</button>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- The EDITING Modal -->
<div id="editForm" class="modal_edit">
    <div class="modal-content_edit">
      <span (click)="save()" class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 70px">Edit OAuthAppProvider</h2>
      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          Client Name:
        </label>
        <!-- <input id="editClientName" type="text" [value]="selectedRowData?.ClientName"> -->
        <input id="editClientName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedRowData.ClientName">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          Version
        </label>
        <!-- <input id="editClientVersion" type="text" [value]="selectedRowData?.Version"> -->
        <input id="editClientVersion" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedRowData.Version">
  </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          API Key:
        </label>
        <!-- <input id="editClientAPIKey" type="text" [value]="selectedRowData?.apiKey"> -->
        <input id="editClientAPIKey" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedRowData.apiKey">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          Protected Secret
        </label>
        <!-- <input id="editClientProtectedSecret" type="text" [value]="selectedRowData?.protectedsecret"> -->
        <input id="editClientProtectedSecret" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedRowData.protectedsecret">
      </div>

      <button style="float: right" class="add" (click)="save()">
        <h4 style="font-style: bold">Save</h4>
      </button>
      <button class="cancel" (click)="save()">
        <h4 style="font-style: bold">Cancel</h4>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!! Thank you so much!!! The only issue I'm having now is updating the view after hitting save. I edited the code for the modal to pull the correct input fields and columns using the method you asked, but the view is still being generated with *ngFor.

Comment: You're welcome. I had just updated my answer with an ngModel solution. Glad you got it working!